# List the file from remote Git repo

Tags: git, wget

I want to get the list of files from the remote git repository and download the files based on the time stamp.

I have tried the command:

```
wget -r -np https://github.com/<username>/exercise
```

But that is showing the file in the HTML format.

Comment: Do you know that `git` and `github` are different things? there is no general way to download distinct files from a remote (esp. via `wget`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to GitHub to view a file, click on the link to the "raw" version. Then you can use the same link to generate others.

Comment: i want to download the file based on the time tat gets created.say i have 10 files and 5 files are created yesterday. i just want to download those  5 yesterday created files alone.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Link is e.g. http://github.com/user/repo/**blob**/master/Licence.md

RAW Link is e.g. http://github.com/user/repo/**raw**/master/Licence.md

(see "raw" button on html page as @Filype stated)

Can you try replacing *blob* with *raw* in the url?

Comment: raw is specific to file.. my requirement is to see the list of files under the dir

Comment: ok, would you mind to edit your question and explain a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You can `git init` a repo, add your target repo as a remote, and then do `git ls-remote`, but a hosted repo will most likely be just a bare repo, with no version-controlled files checked out -- just git objects, refs, etc., and git doesn't store timestamps ...